# lag function over dates when there are same dates with different data

Tags: sql

I am trying to use a lag function, This is how my input looks like

[image]

This is what I am getting now,

[image]

This is my expected output

[image]

This is what I am using currently

```
select 
   dt, 
   lag(dt) over (partition by id, order by dt desc) as next
from t1
```

How can I achieve my desired output

Comment: Need id columns in expected output

Answer (score 1):

We can simply achieve what we're looking for by using `lead()` instead of `lag()`. if `dt = next` then we choose the `max(next)` for the date which is the next date.

```
select  id  
       ,names
       ,dt
       ,case when dt = next then max(next) over(partition by id, dt) else next end as next
from   (
       select * 
             ,lead(dt) over (partition by id order by dt, names) as next
       from    t
       ) t
```

| id | names | dt | next |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | 2021-12-07 | 2021-12-09 |
| 1 | name2 | 2021-12-07 | 2021-12-09 |
| 1 | name3 | 2021-12-09 | null |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SqPzyHtz)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT A.id, A.dt,B.next, A.names
  FROM
  t1 A JOIN 
  (
    SELECT dt,id, LAG(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt DESC) next
    FROM 
     (
       SELECT DISTINCT dt, id
       FROM t1
     ) T
  ) B
ON A.id=B.id AND A.dt=B.dt
```

The idea is to find the LAG date from the distinct date,id values then join this with the table to get the names values.

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/jM5AH5UQ).

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options:

1. For a dynamic approach: use a `CTE` and a `GROUP BY` using your `dt` and `id` columns to eliminate the duplicate `dt` column for the `LAG` window function then `INNER JOIN` the `CTE` to `t1` using `id` and `dt` to get the `names` column.

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT
  id,
  dt,
  LAG(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt DESC) AS next
  FROM t1
 GROUP BY dt, id)
SELECT
   DATE_FORMAT(a.dt,'%m/%d/%Y') AS dt, 
   COALESCE(DATE_FORMAT(b.next,'%m/%d/%Y'),'') AS next,
   a.id,
   a.names
FROM t1 a
INNER JOIN cte b ON a.id = b.id AND a.dt = b.dt
ORDER BY a.names ASC
```

2. For a static approach (specifically for your provided sample data): use `COALESCE` in combination with `LAG` using an offset value of `2` to skip a row otherwise it will be `NULL` and that's when the `COALESCE` function will kick in displaying the first non-`NULL` value via another `LAG`, but this time, without an explicit offset (which will default to `1`) to get the next row's value - without skipping.

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%m/%d/%Y') as dt,
  COALESCE(COALESCE(LAG(DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%m/%d/%Y'), 2) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt DESC), LAG(DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%m/%d/%Y')) over (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt DESC)), '') AS next,
  id,
  names
FROM t1
ORDER BY names ASC
```

**Note:** I've wrapped the `next` column/date in an extra `COALESCE` to replace the `NULL` value with an *empty string* and formatted the date columns to match your expected output.

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/84p6zpB0).

**Result:**

| dt | next | id | names |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/07/2021 | 12/09/2021 | 1 | name1 |
| 12/07/2021 | 12/09/2021 | 1 | name2 |
| 12/09/2021 |  | 1 | name3 |